# wrong answer with the nested if in python

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I expect 3 value in return but my code doesn't return anything .

Thanks

```
a = 3
if a > 0:
    if a == 1:
        print(1)
    elif a == 2:
        print(2)
elif a == 2:
    print(2)
elif a == 3:
    print(3)
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to: `a` equals to `3`, so it goes into the first `if` clause. Then `a` is neither `1` or `2`, so it will do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your first condition is met, `if a > 0`. Because of this the code travels down that path and does not meet the two nested conditions of `a == 1` or `a == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

because a ==3 , your first if is satisfied (other elif(s) will not trigger, because they only trigger if the previous ifs fail), then your code will test if a ==1 or 2 (which is not the case) hence your code prints nothing. Your should modify your code like this

```
a = 3
if a > 0:
    if a == 1:
        print(1)
    elif a == 2:
        print(2)
if a == 2:
    print(2)
if a == 3:
    print(3)
else:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`elif` only executes if the `if` condition is `False`, so you may need:

```
a = 3
if a > 0:
    if a == 1:
        print(1)
    elif a == 2:
        print(2)

if a == 3:
    print(3)
else:
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement is met as the value of a is greater than 0. The result you're looking for could be achieved with the following if/elif block:

```
a = 3
if a == 3:
    print(3)
elif a == 2:
    print(2)
elif a == 1:
    print(1)
else:
    print(a)
```

The above will check the variable for the three conditions, printing the desired result. The else: will catch any other input and print the variable.